# asp.net mvc entity framework code first create database if not exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an issue with entity framework . I am using code first approaching but it is not create the database. It is throw an error with following codes in global.asax:

```
using (resimupDeneme.Data.DataContext db = new DataContext())
        {
            db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        }
```

Here is my picture class :

```
public class foto
{
    public int fotoId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="fotoğraf yolu zorunludur")]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string uzanti{ get; set; }

}
```

And my context class :

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{


    public DataContext() //i find this codes from internet for a solution for my problem but it is not worked 
        : base("DataContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<foto> fotos { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: what error is it throwing?

Comment: it is not throw ride now (interesting) but when i try to see database on sql server object explorer it is not there.

Comment: Have you tried Database First approach just to make sure all your connections are working fine?

Comment: when i try db first i can do my stuff but i cant ever use code first and i really want to use it

Comment: DB is only created if you try to access things related to it. Create the controller and the view (generate them using scaffolding) and access that from your browser. Once you access it you will see the DB will be created. You can also simply query the db table in your Home controller, it will have the same affect.

Comment: Have you executed `Enable-Migrations` on your `Package Manager Console`?

Answer (score 4):

You said in comments:

> it is not throw ride now (interesting) but when i try to see database
>   on sql server object explorer it is not there

Have you actually targeted Sql Server for use with your project?

```
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
```

By default it targets localdb

```
<defaultConnectionFactory
type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory,
EntityFramework">
```

Do you have a connection string in your web.config called `"DataContext"` and if so is it pointing at your SqlServer instance?

..

Beyond that you're doing the same thing multiple times. Remove this from your `using`.

```
db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

And lift this from DataContext:

```
 Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>());
```

and put it either directly into `Application_Start()` or create a EfDatabaseConfig class with a static Config method and call it from `Application_Start()`.

```
EfDatabaseConfig.Configure();
```

Or just use the web.config:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <contexts>
      <context type=" Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1[[Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly]], EntityFramework" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will try it and inform about it .